# Two different versions of jQuery causing failure in event listening

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two versions of jQuery. The code of a meme generator I am using uses jQuery version 1.7.1. The version of jQuery I am using with bootstrap is 2.x The issue is that after I add some code to trigger download after button click it does not work. If I include just my version that is 2.x meme generator stops working. If i include just 1.7.1 the download button event stops listening. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: I would suggest patching the meme generator to work with newer versions of jQuery. Using two versions of jQuery at the same time is a bad idea.

Comment: What does patching exactly mean here? How do I know what in the code is jQuery specific there?

Comment: It would generally mean debugging the code to find which parts are producing errors or failing to work, and manually updating them.

Comment: Firstly try jQuery migrate: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [no conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) for some details.
If possible I would try to use versions which use the same jQuery though, as using two versions in the same page adds a lot of bloat and potential bugs.